# Who is the maker of this valve? Number 12087 on the valve body. Installed 1980

Tags: shower, valve

This is the valve I would like to continue to use with a new cartridge.

[image: valve]

Comment: Isn't there a name on the handle? IDK the maker but while you're in there the valve shouldn't be suspended from the pipes like that.  See if you can screw a board behind it to the studs and mount it to the board.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an old Moen valve.  Parts are sometimes still available.
Kits are available to adapt modern Moen trim kits to these older valves.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Moen. There are a few cartridge options mostly based on how much you want to spend, all preform the same function.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you were to [edit] it to share with us _how_ you know it's a Moen. You know, give a man a fish he eats for a day, teach a man to fish he eats for life...